# How to get result of POST method `$.post()`?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use the following code to POST data:

```
$.post("http://domain/page.aspx", postdata);
```

**UPDATED:**

The following code doesn't work:

```
$.post("http://domain/page.aspx", postdata, function(data){alert(data);});
```

How to get server response as string?

Comment: what error does it throw??

Comment: There is no any error. Nothing.

Comment: open you IE Dev toolbar and check the `network` tab and try to capture the output you get

Comment: I use only FTP to test this simple script (don't have other tools).

Comment: @Altaveron: *"I use only FTP to test this simple script (don't have other tools)."* That's nonsensical. You have a web browser, for instance (you're using it to post on Stack Overflow). FTP has nothing to do with JavaScript code being executed in an HTML page.

Comment: You can't run this script via FTP.  Press F12 in your browser to open the developer console and look in there for errors.  You may need to refresh the page after opening the console (depends what browser you're using).

Comment: Ok, I understand. POST has 'panding' status when I place alert after it. If I remove alert page is changing (hard to stop it). Status of the POST before redirect is 'canceled'.

Comment: @Altaveron: I'm sorry, we can't answer this question as it stands now. You're posting half-complete, vague, contradictory information.

Comment: The information is 100% copy of my code and its result. Nothing more I have at this time.

Comment: @Altaveron: Nonsense. You can use the debugging tools people have pointed out. You can **correctly** quote what they're telling you. You can explain what you think FTP has to do with this. You can, in short, make an effort. Without that, we cannot help you, despite our best intentions.

Comment: The status is pending because it does not hear from the page (it did not get the data from your requested URL, other your function is correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect you're running up against the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which prevents ajax posts cross-origin unless [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) is supported and configured on the server to allow requests from your page's origin (and the browser being used supports it).

Comment: I don't understand the answer but it seems to be right more than others.

Answer (score 1):

Use callback function

```
$.post("http://domain/page.aspx", postdata, function(result) {
    alert(result);
    $('divID').html(result);
});
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly what OP said isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

From your comment

> *Ok, I understand. POST has 'panding' status when I place alert after it. **If I remove alert page is changing (hard to stop it). Status of the POST before redirect is 'canceled'.***

I understand that you make the `.post` call after clicking on some link. You need to cancel the click event so that the link is not followed.

so if you have some code like

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $.post("http://domain/page.aspx", postdata, function(data){alert(data);});
});
```

change it to

```
$('a').click(function(e){ // added e as parameter which get the event
  e.preventDefault(); // added this line which cancels the default action of the click
  $.post("http://domain/page.aspx", postdata, function(data){alert(data);});
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Result: `This request has no response data available`. But other developers may see it - server works well.

Answer (score -1):

`$.post()` has the following description in documentation:

**Description:** Load data from the server using a HTTP POST request.

```
 jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )
```

where,

**url**

```
    Type: String
    A string containing the URL to which the request is sent.
```

**data**

```
    Type: PlainObject or String
    A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.
```

**success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)**

```
    Type: Function()
    A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.
    dataType
    Type: String
    The type of data expected from the server. Default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, text, html).
```

So,

```
$.post("test.php", { "func": "getNameAndTime" },
function(data){
console.log(data.name); // John
console.log(data.time); // 2pm
}, "json");
```

returns JSON data. So use your dataType there and use the function accordingly.

Comment: None of that answers the OP's question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The question is to get the string data as a response. Isn't it? So I am trying to make the user familiar with $.post() parameters which can also accept MIME types.

Comment: @ Bhushan: If you look at the OP's code, it's exactly what you're demonstrating. So that's not useful, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Won't it make difference to include dataType in the $.post() function?

Comment: @ Bhushan: How would we know? We have no idea what the OP is trying to accomplish. But no, not if the response isn't broken. The only reason for using `dataType` in `ajax` calls is if your server code is broken and not returning the correctly `Content-Type` header.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for the tip for when to use Content-Type...thank you very much I was not aware of it.